# Hierarchical entity parent key in NHibernate ByCode

Tags: nhibernate

Using NHibernate 3.2 ByCode configuration, I am attempting to map the following hierarchical entity:

```
public class BusinessType
{
    public virtual Guid BusinessTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid? ParentBusinessTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual String BusinessTypeName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BusinessType> Children { get; set; }
}
```

with this ClassMapping:

```
public class BusinessTypeMapper : ClassMapping<BusinessType>
{
    public BusinessTypeMapper()
    {
        Id(x => x.BusinessTypeId, x => x.Type(new GuidType()));
        Property(x => x.ParentBusinessTypeId, x => x.Type(new GuidType()));
        Property(x => x.BusinessTypeName);
        Set(x => x.Children,
            cm =>
                {
                    // This works, but there is an ugly string in here
                    cm.Key(y => y.Column("ParentBusinessTypeId"));
                    cm.Inverse(true);
                    cm.OrderBy(bt => bt.BusinessTypeName);
                    cm.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
                },
            m => m.OneToMany());
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I'd rather be able to specify the key of the relation using a lambda so that refactoring works.  This seems to be available, as follows:

```
public class BusinessTypeMapper : ClassMapping<BusinessType>
{
    public BusinessTypeMapper()
    {
        Id(x => x.BusinessTypeId, x => x.Type(new GuidType()));
        Property(x => x.ParentBusinessTypeId, x => x.Type(new GuidType()));
        Property(x => x.BusinessTypeName);
        Set(x => x.Children,
            cm =>
                {
                    // This compiles and runs, but generates some other column
                    cm.Key(y => y.PropertyRef(bt => bt.ParentBusinessTypeId));
                    cm.Inverse(true);
                    cm.OrderBy(bt => bt.BusinessTypeName);
                    cm.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
                },
            m => m.OneToMany());
    }
}
```

The problem is that this causes NHibernate to generate a column called `businesstype_key`, ignoring the already-configured `ParentBusinessTypeId`.  Is there any way to make NHibernate use a lambda to specify the relation, rather than a string?

Comment: any reason not to map `public virtual BusinessType Parent { get; set; }`?

Comment: Would that help me solve the problem in my question? I never need to navigate from children to parents, only from parents to children, so I hadn't thought it necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I never need to navigate from children to parents, only from parents
>   to children, so I hadn't thought it necessary

then remove `public virtual Guid? ParentBusinessTypeId { get; set; }` completly. NH will then only create "businesstype_key" (convention) and no "ParentBusinessTypeId". if you want to change that then you have to specify your prefered columnname with `cm.Key(y => y.Column("yourpreferredColumnName"));`

Comment: OK, I can buy that. Seems a stupid convention though, since it uses the property name for all the other columns, resulting in a really inconsistent schema. Out of curiosity, if I do map a Parent property, does that make my original desired result possible?  Also, what is PropertyRef intended for?

Comment: "if I do map a Parent property" -> most probably no, the convention is the same i think. "PropertyRef" -> is used when the foreign key doesnt reference the PrimaryKey but a different property eg. `clientname -> client.name` instead of `client_id -> client.id`